# Who is Jacob? And where did he say this?

Tags: reference-request, history-economic-thought, marxism, gold-standard

In Karl Marx "Das Kapital", in Ch I.1 we find this quote

> "Jacob questions whether gold has ever been paid for at its full
>   value."

Is Jacob Vanderlint? Where in his book “Money Answers all Things” is that claim about gold's value?

Comment: I am just guessing based on some Googling, but William Jacob's [An Historical Inquiry Into the Production, and Consumption of the Precious Metals](https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/72058#page/399/mode/1up) seems more likely. I don't have the line corresponding to the quote however.

Comment: @Giskard Well googled!!! Vol. II, p. 101. Could you please write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You found the page, credit goes to you: please type in all the info in our comments as an answer, and then you can accept it.

Comment: @Giskard Sorry, credit goes to you, you answer to the question Who is Jacob?, William Jacob, and found the place where he said that.

Comment: Very well, I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, in  William Jacob's [An Historical Inquiry Into the Production, and Consumption of the Precious Metals](https://archive.org/stream/historicalinquir02jacorich/historicalinquir02jacorich_djvu.txt), on page 101 it says

> It is probable that in all ages those metals have cost more in their
>   production than their value ever repaid.

This is the likely source of the quote.